# Adding log4j.properties to war file (in Solr application)

Tags: solr, glassfish, log4j

I have a problem with logging in Solr. I want it not to write everything on standard output (I mean glassfish server.log). I want it to use log4j and to write its messages to separate file. I've created log4j.xml file but I don't know if I can add it to the .war file. I've tried external log4j.xml file and setting JVM option -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/{path_to_file} and it worked but only partially. I have some other applications installed on glassfish and all of them started to write to this file. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch Solr's slf4j to log4j, too.
As far as I see, you have to patch the war.

If you are using ant, this snippet could possibly help you with patching it:

```
<project name="solr-war-patching" default="patch" basedir=".">

    <target name="patch" description="Patches solr war file">
        <unjar src="solr.war" dest="solr.war.folder"/>
        <delete file="solr.war.folder/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar" />
        <delete file="solr.war.folder/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar" />
        <copy file="slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar" todir="solr.war.folder/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <copy file="log4j-1.2.16.jar" todir="solr.war.folder/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <jar destfile="solr_patched.war">
            <fileset dir="solr.war.folder" includes="**/**.*" />
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

You have to have the respective jar files for the sl4j api in the folder you call the script...

The log4j.xml can be placed outside the war within the respective app container folder.