# Log formatting in Solr

Tags: logging, solr

Currently, log output for Solr looks like:

```
Feb 23, 2012 6:22:21 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params=    {fl=*+score&wt=json&start=0&q=uid:26261178&rows=1} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
```

on two separate lines, logged to stdout. How can I go about changing the format of the log output to have the timestamp & query metadata info on a single line? I'm trying to script parsing of these logs but the difficulty is increased by having to "take 2" from the log to get all the relevant info for a particular entry.

I'm running vanilla Solr install as given by the example install, i.e. served by Jetty. Using supervisor to control the actual process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a special case of this one:

[Adding log4j.properties to war file (in Solr application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359077/adding-log4j-properties-to-war-file-in-solr-application)

The log file format can be set in a log4j properties file.